# Почему не подключается файл шрифта

Tags: javascript, webpack

Пробую вебпак и не понимаю, что я сделал не так в его настройках.
Не происходит подключение файла шрифта.
В инструментах разработчика во вкладке "Network" вижу что файл шрифта у меня ищется не там где он есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: структура проекта]

конфиг вебпака

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const loader = require("sass-loader");

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log(__dirname);
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const optimization = () => {
    const config = {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all"
        }
    };

    if (!isDev) {
        config.minimizer = [new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(), new TerserWebpackPlugin(),];
    }

    return config;
};

const cssLoaders = (extra) => {
    const loaders = [
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
                publicPath: ""
            }
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        },
    ]

    if (extra) {
        loaders.push(extra)
    }

    return loaders;
}

console.log('IsDev:', isDev);

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
    output:
        {
            filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
        },

    optimization: optimization(),

    devServer: {
        port: 4200
    },

    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin(
            {
                title: 'Evermix',
                template: "./template.html",
                favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'favicon.ico'),
                minify: {
                    collapseWhitespace: !isDev
                }
            }
        ),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
            {filename: "[name].[contenthash].css"}
        ),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: cssLoaders()
            }, {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                use: cssLoaders('sass-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'src/assets/img/[name].[ext]',
                    publicPath: ''
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'src/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',
                    // publicPath: 'src/assets/fonts/',
                }
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

Шрифт объявляю в styles.scss так:

```
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: url("../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
}
```

Comment: Покажите содержимое папки `dist`. Также попробуйте указать правильный путь до шрифта `"../../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf"`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Прошу прощения что не указал изначально. Ошибка взята при использовании скрипта ```"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --mode development"``` Указание правильного пути до шрифта эффекта не возымела

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko содержимое dist http://prntscr.com/z2024v

Comment: Покажите путь, по которому пытается шрифт найти при правильно пути до шрифта.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko сам шрифт у меня находится в ```/src/assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf```.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko при использовании скрипта 'npm run dev' при текущей конфигурации вебпака все ок. Прикладываю Request URL ```http://localhost:4200/src/styles/3cd786652b8a2e9d41f210cb1a527ff6.ttf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был неправильно настроен File Watcher для SCSS. удалил и создал его заново. Работает корректно